# Haskell Simple Function Definition

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I started learning Haskell a few days ago, and I am now learning function types.

Using tuples, below code works.

```
add1 :: (Int,Int) -> Int
add1(x,y) = x + y
```

But what if I want to do the same function without using tuples?

I've tried both function definitions

```
add2 :: Int, Int -> Int
add2 :: Int Int -> Int
```

with

```
add2 a b = a + b
```

But those two function definitions do not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your type should be

```
add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Adding the parentheses will show you what this type actually means.

```
add2 :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

So, add2 is a function that takes an int, and returns another function (type `Int -> Int`).  You use this as follows

```
add2 1 -- this returns a function, type Int -> Int
```

or, add the second parameter to get the final `Int` out

```
(add2 1) 2 --same as "add2 1 2", returns an Int value 1+2=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use **curry** (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry):

```
add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
add2 = curry add1

> add1 (1,2)
3
> add2 1 2
3
```